# sed "unterminated `s'command`" error when running from a script

Tags: perl, sed

I have a `temp` file with contents:

```
a 
b
c
d
e
```

When I run `sed 's#b#batman\nRobin#' temp` from command line, I get:

```
a
batman
Robin
c
d
e
```

However, when I run the command from a Perl scriptL

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

`sed 's#b#batman\nRobin#' temp`
```

It produces error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you run that command in a Perl script? That's like using a calculator as a pencil to do math on a piece of paper.

Comment: `open my $fh, "<", "temp" or die $!; while (<$fh>) { s/b/batman\nRobin/; print; }`

Comment: Replace `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: Absolutely "reproducible" and certainly not "caused by typos."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why run another tool like `sed` once you are inside a Perl program? If anything, now you have far more tools and power so just do it with Perl.

One simple way to do your `sed` thing

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 file(s)\n" if not @ARGV;

while (<>) { 
    s/b/batman\nRobin/;
    print;
}
```

Run this program by supplying the file (`temp`) to it on the command line.  The `die` line is there merely to support/enforce such usage; it is inessential for script's operation.

This program then is a simple filter

- [<> operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads line by line all files submitted on the command line
- A line is assigned by it to [$_ variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_), a default for many things in Perl
- The `s///` operator by default [binds to](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Binding-Operators) `$_`, which gets changed (if pattern matches)
- `print` by default prints the `$_` variable
- Use nearly anything you want for delimiters in regex, see [m//](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc) and [s///](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer) operators

This can also be done as

```
while (<>) {
    print s/b/batman\nRobin/r
}
```

With `/r` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers)  `s///` returns the changed string (or the original if pattern didn't match)

Finally that's also just

```
print s/b/batman\nRobin/r while <>;
```

but I'd expect that with a script you really want to do more and then this probablyisn't it.

On the other side of things you could write it more properly

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

die "Usage: $0 file(s)\n" if not @ARGV;

while (my $line = <>) { 
    chomp $line;

    $line =~ s/b/batman\nRobin/;

    say $line;
}
```

With a line in a [lexical variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) nicely [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp)-ed this is ready for more work.